# Can halal and non-halal food be transported in the same vehicle/container?

Tags: food

Can Halal and Non-Halal food be transported in the same vehicle/same container?

I ask about the container because ten/twenty foot containers or boxes can be changed when operating the same flatbed vehicle. Would not want to mix Halal and Non-Halal foods.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). What is your concern about mixing of halal and haram food in the same container? Transporting haram food is not allowed for a Muslim in general, so what exactly is the context of your question or situation?

Answer (score -2):

Pork and non halal food cannot be transported by a muslim.

> Quran 5:2 do not help others in sin and transgression.
>
> It was narrated from Jaabir ibn ‘Abd-Allaah (may Allaah be pleased with him) that he heard the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say when he was in Makkah at the time of the Conquest: “Allaah and His Messenger have forbidden the sale of alcohol, **dead meat, pork** and idols.” It was said: “O Messenger of Allaah, what do you think of the fat of dead animals, for ships are caulked with it and animal skins are daubed with it, and the people use it to light their lamps?” He said: “No, it is haraam.” Then the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “May Allaah curse the Jews, for when Allaah forbade them animal fat, they melted it down and sold it, and consumed its price. (Bukhari and muslim)

Transporting haram foods and consuming its price is haraam based upon the above hadith and Quranic verse

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how "do not help others in sin and transgression" implies "Pork and non halal food cannot be transported by a muslim."  It seems like a strict reading of that verse (given the [multiple translations](http://islamawakened.com/quran/5/2/)); are there scholars who come to the same conclusion in the same way?

Comment: I noticed your hadith, could you comment on [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/93) which seems to contradict it? "

The Prophet (ﷺ) saw a dead sheep which had been given in charity to a freed slave-girl of Maimuna, the wife of the Prophet (ﷺ) . The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Why don't you get the benefit of its hide?" They said, "It is dead." He replied, "**Only to eat (its meat) is illegal.**""

Comment: Prophet was asked about "fat and skin of dead animals" . In the other hadith it's skin of sheep. May Allah correct our affairs. Skin of dead sheep is usable.

Comment: Yes but what if I can separate the storage, and get a non-Muslim to transport it? For example, trucks which have different compartments, and I set it up as one for Halal food, one for Non-Halal food?

Comment: definitely this approach is better than carrying non halal food